# Store Array into variable in php

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, foreach

I run Following SQL query in WordPress.

```
$mylink = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `object_id` FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = (SELECT `term_id` FROM `wp_terms` WHERE `slug` LIKE 'jabong')");
```

And display value From Array.

```
foreach($mylink as $key => $row) {
echo $row->object_id."<br>";
}
```

I Got following Output.
109957109834109952109964109670

i want to store this value Like String
109957,109834,109952,109964,109670.
So please Help me how to store this value in string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "";foreach($mylink as $key => $row) { $sting.=$row->object_id.",
"; }

$string = substr($string,0,-1);
```